# `int('10**2')` raises `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10**2'` despite `type(10**2)` being `<class 'int'>`

Tags: python, input, integer, user-input, literals

`int('10**2')` raises `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10**2'` despite `type(10**2)` being `<class 'int'>`.

I take input `n` as `n = input()`, then I do `int(n)`. When I input `10**2`, I get `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10**2'`.

I'm guessing the issue is that `10**2` is not a literal - it has to be evaluated first, but I'm hesitant to do `int(eval(n))` since `n` can be any string.

---

By contrast, `float('1e2')` despite being very similar, doesn't raise an error. I guess `1e2` is considered a literal...? and doesn't have to be evaluated?

---

My current workaround is to check whether the string contains `'**'` and if it does, handle it accordingly:

```
n = input()
if '**' in n:
  base, exp, *a = n.split('**')
  if a:
    raise ValueError(f'This input, {n}, can't be interpreted as an integer')
  n = int(base)**int(exp)
else:
  n = int(n)
```

or to support expressions like `3**3**3`:

```
n = input()
if '**' in n:
  operands = input.split('**')
  # '**' associates to the right
  exp = 1
  while operands:
    base = int(operands.pop())
    exp = base ** exp
  n = exp
else:
  n = int(n)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `10**2` must be evaluated while `1e2` is a constant. I suggest taking a look at [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string) for some options regarding parsing mathematical expressions in strings.